# Can I paste a long code in a loop in python

Tags: python

if you have a 200 line code and you want to paste in a loop, how would you do it, without ruining the loop

i tried this:

```
code = [
your 200 line code
]

while True:
    if example = example
        code
    else:
        exit()
```

and expected to work. Help please

Comment: See [python functions](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp)

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What do you mean by copy? And if it is actual copy paste thing. Why do you even need that?

Comment: so you want to store lines of code in a list and then run the code over and over? It's not clear exactly what you're asking for. I believe you need to show a much more complete [mre]. But if that is indeed what you are asking for, it is very unlikely that that's actually the best way to solve the issue you're trying to solve. Because you didn't actually tell us what issue you're trying to solve, but instead are asking about this strange-sounding solution, I'm inclined to believe that this is an example of the [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: `eval('\n'.join(code))` will do what you asked for, but almost certainly not what you want.

Comment: Are you asking about indenting all 200 lines to be inside the `if` block (which should have a colon `:`) at the end of the line??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just highlight everything you want to be in the loop and press tab (adding indent)